# CUDA Fortran CURAND Device API Issues

Tags: cuda, fortran, gpu, gpgpu, pgi

Context: I'm trying to do some pseudorandom number generation at the GPU using CURAND, but since I'm using CUDA fortran I have to create an interface module, which interfaces the CURAND LIBRARY functions written in C. Here is the interface code:

```
    interface curand_init

      attributes(device) subroutine curand_init(seed,sequence,offset,state) &
        bind(C,name='curand_init')
        use iso_c_binding
        integer(c_long_long),value :: seed
        integer(c_long_long),value :: sequence
        integer(c_long_long),value :: offset
        !pgi$ ignore_tr state
        real(c_float), device :: state(*)   
      end subroutine curand_init

    end interface curand_init

    interface curand

      attributes(device) subroutine curand(state) &
        bind(C,name='curand')
        use iso_c_binding
        !pgi$ ignore_tr state
        real(c_float),device :: state(*)
      end subroutine curand

    end interface curand

    interface curand_uniform

      attributes(device) subroutine curand_uniform(state) &
        bind(C,name='curand_uniform')
        use iso_c_binding
        !pgi$ ignore_tr state
        real(c_float),device :: state(*)
      end subroutine curand_uniform

      attributes(device) subroutine curand_uniform_double(state) &
      bind(C,name='curand_uniform_double')
        use iso_c_binding
        !pgi$ ignore_tr state
        real(c_double),device :: state(*)
      end subroutine curand_uniform_double

    end interface curand_uniform

    interface curand_normal

      attributes(device) subroutine curand_normal(state) &
        bind(C,name='curand_normal')
        use iso_c_binding 
        !pgi$ ignore_tr state
        real(c_float),device :: state(*)
      end subroutine curand_normal 

      attributes(device) subroutine curand_normal_double(state) &
        bind(C,name='curand_normal_double')
        use iso_c_binding
        !pgi$ ignore_tr state
        real(c_double),device :: state(*)
      end subroutine curand_normal_double

    end interface curand_normal
```

in the same module I make a call to this device subroutine `call curand_init(seed,id,0,tmpconf)` in a global kernel. I get this error when I call the global kernel.

```
gpu_gen_m.CUF:
PGF90-S-0155-Could not resolve generic procedure curand_init (gpu_gen_m.CUF: 99)
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   1 severes, 0 fatal for gen_conf
```

any Idea how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Just an advice, use some indentation in your code. Your interfaces are very hard to read.

Comment: How are `seed,id,0,tmpconf` defined?

Comment: There is no reason for the generic interface for `curand_init`, change it to a normal interface and you will get more direct error message.

Comment: `integer(kind=int_ptr_kind ()) :: seed , id` and `real(fp_kind), allocatable, device :: tmp_d(:)` where `fp_kind = singlePrecision`

Answer (score 1):

In the interface you have

```
integer(c_long_long),value :: seed
integer(c_long_long),value :: sequence
integer(c_long_long),value :: offset
!pgi$ ignore_tr state
real(c_float), device :: state(*)
```

but in the call you use

two times `integer(kind=int_ptr_kind ())`, one `integer` and one `real(fp_kind)`

That cannot work, you must have the same types in the call.

If you delete the superficial name of the interface, which makes the interface generic, you will get more direct error message from the compiler.